# Recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 from Windows 10, getting severe lag when moving cursor through menus. help?

Tags: drivers, mouse, 22.04

I got a pretty junk system, Pentium J3710, 4gigs ram, 1 tb hdd, and recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 since I was again fed up with windows bugs. I have installed ubuntu several times before but this time I am facing severe lag while scrolling or simply hovering the mouse cursor over any animated selections menu or interfaces. I disabled animations and still problem persists. I did not connect to the internet while installing the distro, but simple ticked the normal installation and install third party drivers and stuff option. Any help is appreciated :). The whole ui feels stuttery and laggy although apps run and open faster than windows. I think this might be some problem with the graphics driver although I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you think the graphics driver is causing the problem, you can try switching the driver in the software & updates GUI under the additional driver tab where you will find a list of drivers to choose from. Alternatively, you can consider using lighter distro.

Comment: Full Ubuntu assumes newer better hardware. You may want to try a lightweight flavor. Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours  I use Kubuntu, midweight flavor, on my desktops\  and was surprised it worked on an old 2006 laptop, not speedy but functional where Ubuntu would not even install.

Comment: thanks for the info, i will install try them..ill inform if the problem persists.. :)

Comment: @oldfred thank you for your suggestion, I installed Lubuntu and its a breeze, all my Ubuntu apps work perfectly, faster even. Thank you I'll close this question.

Comment: agree, Lubuntu is very good for older pcs. If you want a 'light' office suite, try Free Office (Libreoffice may be too 'heavy', and it has bugs). For browser, Firefox and Chromium are now snaps, which can be buggy for older systems. A good browser is Slimjet, which can be downloaded as a deb.

Answer (score 0):

As @oldfred said,
"Full Ubuntu assumes newer better hardware. You may want to try a lightweight flavor. Light weight flavors: Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie ubuntu.com/download/flavours "
Personally I fixed my issue by switching over to Lubuntu and its superfast now.