# why gnomeshell's systray's menu lags so much? and how to fix it (is there any dconf or some other option I could use even to recompile gnome)?

Tags: 22.04, gnome-shell, freeze, wayland, tweak

if I hover the mouse over anything on systray, it is fast.
The moment I click in something there that shows a menu, between hovering over every menu entry, there is a whole interface freeze (everything in the screen) for 1s to 3s!

I run this in some terminal and keep watching it while I hover over systray menu's options:
`while true;do echo -n .;sleep 0.1;done`

It is not full RAM nor a swapping problem. Ram is 62% used. I checked also for IOWait, no problems.
But I noticed, in `htop` that the CPU usage of gnome-shell raises a lot up to >=100%. And if I keep moving the mouse non stop on the menus (trying to make the entries keep being highlighted) the whole interface will not update until I stop moving the mouse and calmly wait several seconds!

Is there something I can to to fix it?
accessibility/Animations option is already disabled.

I wonder what could cause that is it just makes no sense to me. Why updating a highlight in a menu would freeze the whole window manager? it looks not like requiring a stronger hardware, it just looks like something that could be disabled (like disabling the very menu entry highlighting), or telling gnomeshell to render the menus in a simpler way that doesnt require interrupting the whole WM...

ubuntu 22.04, wayland.

related, but I am asking for a way to tweak ubuntu because I use many gnome things that I dont know if LUbuntu will have alternatives: [Recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 from Windows 10, getting severe lag when moving cursor through menus. help?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409881/recently-installed-ubuntu-22-04-from-windows-10-getting-severe-lag-when-moving)

it seems that after gnome-shell memory leak reaches about 1GB, even after `sudo swapoff -a`, the menu begins to slowdown and the machine begins to overheat (raised 10oC), if I keep insisting in not restart the system, just suspend, on every wakeup from suspend it increases about 75MB the memory loak. So, soon I guess it will be super slow again and overheating will raise a total of 15oC.

some old test results if you want to read.

> I was wondering installing LUbuntu (lightweight) but I will lose gnome. Then I finally had to restart, so I updated all possible packages first. Just after restart, gnome-shell was using 300MB of RAM. Now it is at 430MB of RES in htop, after a few wakeups from suspend (after 2 days it is 915MB now, I guess in 1 or 2 weeks w/o a system restart the problem may happen again). If I knew this tip https://superuser.com/a/1443379/1880812 about what apps are using the swap I could confirm. But while it was lagging a lot, gnome-shell was using 1.6GB of RES, and there was some GB in the SWAP too, so my guess it that may be gnome-shell would be using much more memory and most of it was in the SWAP. As soon it happens again I will update here, because everything is super fast again now, and CPU temperature also lowered in about 10oC (while it was lagging it was heating more too). So, may be the tip of the dude that deleted his comment could be right. gnome-shell may be swapping a lot because of memory leaks/bloating, even if there is still a good amount of available RAM. (I will shorten this text later too when I get more test results) but if gnome-shell could unload all its internal data and reload it, that could solve the memory leak problem for machines that are not restarted often!.

Comment: no, it is not ram nor swap. Ram is 62% used. I checked also for IOWait, no problems. but I noticed, in `htop` that the CPU usage of gnome-shell raises a lot up to +100%. And if I keep moving the mouse non stop on the menus (trying to make the entries keep being highlighted) the whole interface will not update until I stop moving the mouse! :O

Comment: I found that the gnome-shell memory leak that is what apparently make it lag, forces me to restart the machine every 10 to 15 days. I could just re-login, but reconfiguring development environment takes the same time so I prefer to restart. And as I have to, I also update everything before restarting. So I wonder if them not fixing the memory leak could be to indirectly force users to upgrade the system, mainly about critical security packages (or may be force to buy more RAM)?